# React unit test getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Component')

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

I'm new to React and React unit testing. I'm trying to create a simple test and am getting the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Component')" Here's my code.

**HelloWorld.js**

```js
import React from "react";

class HelloWorld extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( < h1 > My First ReactJS Core App! < /h1>);
    }
  }
  export default HelloWorld
```

**test.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  HelloWorld
} from "../wwwroot/src/react/HelloWorld"
import {
  render,
  screen
} from "@testing-library/react";

describe("apptest", () => {
  it("works", () => {
    render( < HelloWorld / > );
    screen.getByText("My First ReactJS Core App!");
  });
});
```

When I run "npm test", I get the following:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had my original code in a .jsx file. The code got transpiled to a .js file which I was referencing in my test. Again, I don't know much about transpiling but when I created a new js file and imported that, the test passed.

Answer (score 0):

When I see your code, you don't have `Component` importing, but the error message shows `React.Component`.
Does your original code match with your attached code?

If it is, please try to add the following import.

`import React, {Component} from 'react'`

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Temp extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1> My First ReactJS Core App! </h1>;
  }
}
export default Temp;


import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Temp from "./Temp";

describe("apptest", () => {
  it("works", () => {
    render(<Temp />);
    screen.getByText("My First ReactJS Core App!");
  });
});
```

Comment: Apologies for the screenshot result not matching the code. I had tried both "extends React.Component" and "extends Component" with "import {Component}".  I get the same error message both ways.